# Selective div hiding with IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four columns detailing the changelogs of a game and I'd like to add an option allowing users to simply click a button and only have them view the most recent updates. Each update has it's own div. Would I be able to do so through JQuery by adding an id to these most recent update divs such as "current" and on the click of a button, remove all divs with the class "update" that do not have the "current" id?

Four Columns --> Each column having a most recent update looking like so :-

```
<div class="ch-update">
            <div class="ch-update-header active">
                Minecraft 1.5.1
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Fixed a bunch of bugs</li>
                <li>Improved performance</li>
                <li>Notable: Crash on Mac OS X on "OpenGL Function Not Supported"</li>
                <li>Notable: Unable to place paintings</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: code stuff required plz......!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement-

*remove all divs with the class "update" that do not have the "current" id*

I think this should be done this way:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('.update:not(#current)').fadeOut().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than maintaining your state through classes, you may want to just take advantage of the DOM ordering.  I.e., simply remove all the `div`'s that aren't the last one.  E.g.,

I'm of course making assumptions about your markup here, since it wasn't provided.  But the interaction might look something like this:

```
$('#view-recent-for-column-1').click(function() {
    $('#column-1 > div').slice(0, -1).remove();
});
```

Comment: My markup has now been added to the OP. Would this method allow for four most recent updates, one in each column?